# sobreescribir listas

Tags: python

Estoy programando el juego del ahorcado, y esta yendo dentro de todo bien, pero estoy atascado con algo.

El usuario elige una letra y esta se ve reflejada en pantalla, mostrando a esta letra en sus casillas correspondientes pero cada vez que el usuario elije una letra, se pierden las que había elegido con anterioridad, como se puede ver:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que yo quiero hacer es que se sobrescriban en una lista todas las anteriores letras que había elegido, pero en vez de eso, simplemente se van concatenando.

Este es el código:

```
import pyfiglet
import random
import os

def start():
    print(pyfiglet.figletformat("BIENVENIDO AL JUEGO DEL AHORCADO"))
    print("""
    ¡ A D I V I N A   L A   P A L A B R A !
    """)

def game():
    with open("./archivos/data.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        palabras = list(f)
        palabra = random.choice(palabras)
        palabra = palabra.replace("\n", "") 

    letras = [i for i in palabra]
    guiones = []

    for i in letras:
        guiones.append("")

    print(" ".join(guiones))
    print("")

    guiones = []
    while guiones != letras:
        letra = input("Elige una letra: ")


        for i in palabra:
            if i == letra:
                guiones.append(letra)
            else:
                guiones.append("_")
        print(" ".join(guiones)) 

        guiones.clear() 


def run():
    start()
    game()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

Answer (score 1):

Cuando eliges una letra, sólo compruebas si existe esa letra en la palabra, borrando la lista `guiones` con cada iteración. **No guardas ningún *estado* anterior**.

Voy por pasos:

Para convertir una cadena a lista de caracteres es más fácil así:

```py
letras = list(palabra)
```

Para guardar la solución como `guiones` podemos construir así la lista:

```py
guiones = ['_'] * len(palabra)
```

En cada iteración, debemos guardar en `guiones` las letras descubiertas:

```py
for i, c in enumerate(letras):
    if c == letra:
        guiones[i] = letra

print(" ".join(guiones))
```

El código completo:

```py
import pyfiglet
import random
import os

def start():
    print(pyfiglet.figletformat("BIENVENIDO AL JUEGO DEL AHORCADO"))
    print("""
    ¡ A D I V I N A   L A   P A L A B R A !
    """)

def randword():
    with open("./archivos/data.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        palabras = list(f)
        palabra = random.choice(palabras)
        palabra = palabra.replace("\n", "")

    return palabra
    

def game():
    letras = list(randword())
    guiones = ['_'] * len(letras)

    print(" ".join(guiones))
    print("")

    while guiones != letras:
        letra = input("Elige una letra: ")

        for i, c in enumerate(palabra):
            if c == letra:
                guiones[i] = letra

        print(" ".join(guiones))

    print("FINAL")


def run():
    start()
    game()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```